# Recursive finding the indexes of 2 biggest nums in massive (C)

Tags: c, search, recursion

I have broken my head trying to solve this question on an exam. I'm stil shocked by it.

Can anybody help me write a function:

```
void get2(int a[], int n, *i1, *i2)
```

that receives the massive a[] of integers and his length n and saves to pointers i1 and i2 the indexes of the two biggest numbers in the massive (`i1` - the biggest, `i2` - the second biggest).

The solution must be recursive and can not contain loops. It has be done by the complextiy of O(n). The numbers in the massive are all diffrent. We cant use any helper functions.

There aren't any additional conditions. I tried some solutions, but they werent good enough. 
I dont know how to save the indexes without losing there values when I recurse.

There was additional hint, that I should pay attention to how I use the `*i1`, `*i2` to pass information between recursive steps, but i tried to use it some how and it didn't work for me anything I tried. Help somebody ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Just call `qsort` to sort the array in descending order, then return `*i1 = 0` and `*i2 = 1`. That seems to fulfill all the requirements as stated, no ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an extremly important condition ) Will fix it right now

Comment: @user183297 What do two biggest nums mean? If for example an array contain at least two beggest numbers with the same value as for example { 1, 2, 2 } then are two biggest numbers 2 and 2 or 2 and 1?

Comment: dam it, i forgot the second very important condition. The numbers all diffrent in the massive. Sorry, its the exam. Ill fix it right now. And there are at least 2 numbers in the massive.

Comment: Can you have extra helper functions?

Comment: @user183297 The pointers can not refer indices because there are no such objects as indices in the function. I think that the pointers should refere the elements themselves.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one trick to play on this exercise: *Recognize when we are in the outermost recursive call and when we are not, or simpler terms when the current call of `get2` is the first one and when it is not*.

Using the pointers and the `n` parameter to do some basic *Divide et Impera* strategy is straightforward and require no further explanation.

We need to tell the first and subsequent calls because in the first, and only there, call we need to initialize the pointers.

We cannot rely on `i1` or `i2` values as they are uninitialized.
Only `n` has enough structure to carry some information: *When we are called from the extern, i.e. not by recurring, then `n >= 0`*.
We can then perform the one-time initialization and then **negate** `n`. This way if `n<=0` we know that we are in the recursive calls.

However we still have a problem: if `n >= 0` then it's opposite is `n <= 0`. The two condition overlaps for `n == 0`.
This will make the initialization happen two time and further worst the second one at the end of the recursion stack thereby voiding the state calculated.
In order to avoid them, the `n` is not simply negated but **negated and decremented by 1**, so the `5` becomes `-6`.
We can then recover the usable value of `n` by again negating and decrementing by 1. In the code below this is done and stored in `m`.

The `else` part is straightforward as pointed above.  We only additionally check that the second maximal element is not equal to the maximal element in the second `if`.
If one index is `-1` it means that it is not pointing to any element and can be assigned unconditionally.

When the function return, `i1` cannot point to `-1` unless the array is empty.
`i2` can point to `-1` if all elements are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get2(int a[], int n, int* i1, int* i2)
{
    /*  Transform from encoded n to actual length */
    int m = -n-1;

    /* Is this the first call? */
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        /* Initialize the pointer to -1, i.e. no elements */
        *i1 = *i2 = -1;

        /* Start the recursion, encode the length */
        get2(a, -n-1, i1, i2);
    }
    /* Here we are in the subsequent calls, we use m and not n */
    else if (m-- > 0)
    {
        /* Assign i1 */
        if (*i1 == -1 || a[m] > a[*i1])
        {
            *i2 = *i1;    /* Don't forget to update i2 too! */
            *i1 = m;
        }
        /* Opportunity to assign i2, check that the second max != max */
        else if ((*i2 == -1 || a[m] > a[*i2]) && a[m] != a[*i1])
        {
            *i2 = m;
        }

        /* Tail recursion, do proper encoding of the n parameter */
        get2(a, -m-1, i1, i2);  
    }
}
```

This function can be tested with this code

```
void test(int a[], int n)
{
    int max, smax, i;

    get2(a, n, &max, &smax);

    printf("------------------------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    printf("\nMax is ");
    if (max >= 0)
        printf("%d", a[max]);
    else 
        printf("NOT FOUND");

    printf("\nSecond Max is ");
    if (smax >= 0)
        printf("%d\n", a[smax]);
    else 
        printf("NOT FOUND\n");
}

int main()
{
    int v1[] = {};
    int v2[] = {1};
    int v3[] = {1,2};
    int v4[] = {2, 1};
    int v5[] = {2, 2};
    int v6[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int v7[] = {4,3,2,1};
    int v8[] = {2,1,4,3};
    int v9[] = {2,2,2,2};
    int v10[] = {1,2,3,4,3,2,1};
    int v11[] = {1,1,2,3,4,4};

    test(v1, 0);
    test(v2, 1);
    test(v3, 2);
    test(v4, 2);
    test(v5, 2);
    test(v6, 4);
    test(v7, 4);
    test(v8, 4);
    test(v9, 4);
    test(v10, 7);
    test(v11, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

With the below output

```
------------------------------

Max is NOT FOUND
Second Max is NOT FOUND
------------------------------
1
Max is 1
Second Max is NOT FOUND
------------------------------
1 2
Max is 2
Second Max is 1
------------------------------
2 1
Max is 2
Second Max is 1
------------------------------
2 2
Max is 2
Second Max is NOT FOUND
------------------------------
1 2 3 4
Max is 4
Second Max is 3
------------------------------
4 3 2 1
Max is 4
Second Max is 3
------------------------------
2 1 4 3
Max is 4
Second Max is 3
------------------------------
2 2 2 2
Max is 2
Second Max is NOT FOUND
------------------------------
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
Max is 4
Second Max is 3
------------------------------
1 1 2 3 4 4
Max is 4
Second Max is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you another hint instead of writing the actual code for you:

You have 4 arguments, use all of them to pass the relevant data to the recursive calls. What I mean by that is - the first 2 arguments can describe the part of the array that is interesting for us, the pointers store the largest integers we have found, you modify them each time you find a bigger one.

And here lies the trap that most likely caught you - those are `int *`, that is a pointer to an integer. What the function receives is simply an address in memory. If you set that pointer to point to anything, the caller will not receive that data. You can simply write directly to that address instead of setting the pointer, like so:

```
int myInteger;
int *ptr = &myInteger;
*ptr = 123;
```

Comment: Yes, but finally I need to send the biggest and the second biggest indexes to the original addresses that were given to me at the first place. I cant lose them either.

Comment: As I wrote, just write to the addresses the pointers point to. I only intended to show you the syntax with the code in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-threadsafe way to do it: by keeping track of the original start of the array using a `static` variable. The addresses of the largest elements are stored in the pointers, which are used as pointers to pointers, and right at the end they are replaced by the indexes of the elements by using some pointer arithmetic aided by the static variable.

```
void get2(int a[], int n, int *one, int *two) {
    static int *arr_start = 0;
    if (n > 0) {
        if (arr_start == 0) {
            arr_start = a;
        }
        if (a[0] > **((int **)one)) {
            *one = a;
        } else if (a[0] > **((int **)two)) {
            *two = a;
        }
        get2(a + 1, n - 1, one, two);
    } else {
        *one = *((int **)one) - arr_start;
        *two = *((int **)two) - arr_start;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Without using `static` variables: Use the second pointer as an indicator of whether or not we have already allocated space to keep track of the the start of the array and the indexes. Use the allocated space to keep track of the initial array size and the two largest indexes, then assign them to the correct pointers at the end:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void get2(int a[], int n, int *one, int *two) {
    int **pp_one = (int **)one;
    if (*two != NULL) {
         *pp_one = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
         (*pp_one)[0] = n;
         (*pp_one)[1] = 0;
         (*pp_one)[2] = 0;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        if (a[0] > (*pp_one)[1]) {
            (*pp_one)[1] = a;
        } else if (a[0] > (*pp_one)[2]) {
            (*pp_one)[2] = a;
        }
        get2(a + 1, n - 1, one, two);
    } else {
        int *t = *one;
        *two = (*pp_one)[1] - (*pp_one)[0];
        *one = (*pp_one)[2] - (*pp_one)[0];
        free(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Oli, but im affraid of I cant use static variables at all. Any seem able way to solve it without it ? 
Or maybe it unsolvable ?

Comment: Hmm, did they say what the initial values of the pointers were by chance?

Comment: @user183297 that's the third condition you have added yet your question still says there are no other conditions.

Comment: That what confused me the most. If they were initial, its the smallest problem, but I asked the lecturer during the exam and she said to me, that we dont know even if they initial. But let us suggest, if you can solve it like that, that they are some randomal values initialized. 
If you succeed that way, maybe I didnt understand very well and I can claim disinformation or something. 
And maybe after we will find some solution in the option that they initialized, we will understand more clearly what to do, if they arent initialized or maybe what is the mistake.

Comment: Can anyone give me V and 5 points, so i could print an image in my answer to the question ? 
We have found the solution, it is much cleverer that i though. But I dont have enough points to add images.

Answer (score 0):

Just another try on your function prototype,

```
void get2(int a[], int n, int *i1, int *i2)
{
    if(n <= 0)
      return;

    if(*i1 == -1 && n < 2){//initial a[] is null or with only one element
      *i1 = n-1; 
      return;
    }

    if(*i1 == -1 && n >=2){
      if(a[n-1] > a[n-2]){
        *i1 = n-1;
        *i2 = n-2;
      }else{
        *i1 = n-2;
        *i2 = n-1;
      }
      return get2(a, n-2, i1, i2);
    }

    int max= a[*i1], less = a[*i2];
    if(a[n-1] > max){
        *i2 = *i1;
        *i1 = n-1;
    }else if (a[n-1] > less){
        *i2 = n-1;
    }
    get2(a, n-1, i1, i2);
}
```

Test as follows,

```
int main()
{
   int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 0};
   int maxIndex = -1, lessIndex= -1;
   get2(a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(int),&maxIndex,&lessIndex);
   printf("maxIndex=%d(value:%d), lessIndex=%d(value:%d)\n",  
                maxIndex,a[maxIndex],lessIndex, a[lessIndex]);
}
```

Output,

> maxIndex=5(value:8), lessIndex=4(value:7)

Comment: The function is invalid.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Could you give some detailed guide to refine? It seems work.

Comment: Consider the case when n is equal to 1, In this case this declaration int max= a[*i1], less = a[*i2]; has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks. you are right. I updated to add condition to return when the initial a[] is only with one element. Actually, I found my implementation depends the initial input *i1 == -1 to judge the first run, it seems not a good practise?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the brain teaser. It sounded like an interesting problem. Even though it's homework, I decided to solve it.

This gets a bit annoying to do without having the indices pre-initialized somehow, but it's doable. Sounds like an artificial restriction to create artificial pain.

```
void
get2(int a[], int n, int *i1, int *i2) {
        if (n == 0) {
                *i1 = *i2 = -1;
                return;
        }
        get2(&a[1], n - 1, i1, i2);

        if (*i1 != -1)
                (*i1)++;
        if (*i2 != -1)
                (*i2)++;

        if (*i1 == -1) {
                *i1 = 0;
        } else if (*i2 == -1 || a[*i2] < a[0]) {
                *i2 = 0;
                if (a[*i1] < a[0]) {
                        *i2 = *i1;
                        *i1 = 0;
                }
        }
}
```

Here we just recurse until we have no array left to look at, then initialize the indices and on the way back we figure out the indices we're interested in. On the way back through all the recursions we update the indices i1 and i2 if they are initialized to properly point into the array we have in this iteration, then if i1 isn't initialized yet, then we know that n == 0 and must be the biggest element. On iterations after that we know that is the only interesting element of the array is element 0, if that's not bigger than a[*i2], then it's not bigger than a[*i1] either. If it is (or we're just initializing i2), we compare to see if we need to swap i1 and i2.

"But wait!", you might yell. "You're not doing tail recursion, if the array is massive you will run out of stack.". Glad you mentioned it, in fact, C doesn't say anything about the compiler having to do optimizations for tail recursion so I'd like to argue that any solution has to account for this problem. Here's a solution that works on the same principles (run out of array before we initialize the indices) that solves this in O(log n) stack space:

```
void
get2(int a[], int n, int *i1, int *i2) {
        /*
         * Reset the indices at the end of the recursion.
         */
        switch (n) {
        case 0:
                *i1 = -1;
                *i2 = -1;
                return;
        case 1:
                *i1 = 0;
                *i2 = -1;
                return;
        }
        /*
         * Number of elements in the lower and upper halves of the array.
         * Notice the '+ (n & 1)' which is there to add one element to the
         * upper half of the array if n is odd.
         *
         * The asserts document the invariants.
         */

        int lower_half = n / 2, upper_half = (n / 2) + (n & 1);
        int li1, li2, ui1, ui2;

        assert(lower_half >= 1);
        assert(upper_half >= 1);
        assert(lower_half + upper_half == n);

        get2(&a[0], n - upper_half, &li1, &li2);
        get2(&a[lower_half], n - lower_half, &ui1, &ui2);
        ui1 += lower_half;
        if (ui2 != -1)
                ui2 += lower_half;

        assert(li1 != -1);
        assert(ui1 != -1);
        assert(li2 == -1 || a[li2] < a[li1]);
        assert(ui2 == -1 || a[ui2] < a[ui1]);
        if (a[li1] < a[ui1]) {
                *i1 = ui1;
                if (ui2 == -1 || a[li1] > a[ui2])
                        *i2 = li1;
                else
                        *i2 = ui2;
        } else if (a[li1] > a[ui1]) {
                *i1 = li1;
                if (li2 == -1 || a[ui1] > a[li2])
                        *i2 = ui1;
                else
                        *i2 = li2;
        } else {
                *i1 = li1;
                if (li2 == -1 || a[ui2] > a[li2])
                        *i2 = ui2;
                else
                        *i2 = li2;
        }
}
```

I'm not going to explain it, the comments and asserts should be enough to show what's going on. I'm pretty sure that the big block of ifs at the end can be written much more efficiently, but I didn't bother.

It might not be perfectly correct, it worked on the first try with a few test cases taken from the previous answers and I didn't do more testing. There might be some edge cases I haven't considered, but the general idea works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice answer I got. The next few strokes are just to get enough characters to publish my answer with this image. this it requieres 30 characters, so i wiil write anything.

It's brilliant as simple as it is. Isnt it ))?
* This code need a little correction, with one more condition, if one of the pointers is NULL, not to loop.
[image: Here is a nice answer I got]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it.  This implementation is pretty concise.

```
void get2(int a[], int n, int *i1, int *i2)
{
    if (n == 0) return;

    if (*i1 == -1 || a[n-1] > a[*i1]) {
        *i2 = *i1;
        *i1 = n-1;
    } else if (*i2 == -1 || a[n-1] > a[*i2]) {
        *i2 = n-1;
    }
    get2(a, n-1, i1, i2);
}
```

To test:

```
#define NUM 10

int main()
{
    int a[NUM];
    int i, i1, i2;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<NUM;i++) {
        a[i] = rand() & 0xFFFF;
        fprintf(stderr,"%d ",a[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"\n");

    i1 = i2 = -1;
    get2(a,NUM,&i1,&i2);

    fprintf(stderr,"i1=%d, i2=%d\n", i1, i2);
    fprintf(stderr,"a[i1]=%d, a[i2]=%d\n", a[i1], a[i2]);
}
```